# TableView Cell skips with the color

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

The color of the respective cells is not the ones I specified.

Each row with "Online" should be white and each row with "Offline" should be slightly green. This all works, but as soon as I scroll down and up, the ones that are on "Online" get the color green as background color...

[image: Colour of the table]

```
tblIP.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Device>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Device item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(item == null || empty) {
                setStyle("");
                setText(null);
                this.getStyleClass().add("Offline");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("Online");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("deactive");
            } else if (!item.getActive().get()){
                this.getStyleClass().remove("Offline");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("Online");
                this.getStyleClass().add("deactive");
            } else if (item.getStatus().get() == 1) {
                this.getStyleClass().remove("Offline");
                this.getStyleClass().add("Online");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("deactive");
            } else if (item.getStatus().get() == 0){
                this.getStyleClass().add("Offline");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("Online");
                this.getStyleClass().remove("deactive");
            }
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```css
.Offline {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(217,153,153);
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.Online {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.deactive {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(196,215,155);
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

So that with the color assignment works so far, but that when I scroll that does not color correctly. I guess that I scroll too fast and the "updateItem" does not come behind.

Comment: Please write your question in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English only site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: when having problems when scrolling, most often the logic of adding/removing styles is somehow wrong (f.i. style classes can be added more than once, so they tend to accumulate if not cleaned completely)

Comment: How can I clean this up? The problem is that when I scroll down the table, the actual white fields are green.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okey I have solved the problem myself. In that I simply added this.getStyleClass().clear();.

The Code:

```
tblIP.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Device>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Device item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            this.getStyleClass().removeAll("deactive", "Online", "Offline"); <- Thanks James_D
            if(item == null || empty) {
                setStyle("");
                setText(null);
            } else if (!item.getActive().get()){
                this.getStyleClass().add("deactive");
            } else if (item.getStatus().get() == 1) {
                this.getStyleClass().add("Online");
            } else if (item.getStatus().get() == 0){
                this.getStyleClass().add("Offline");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's probably better to do `this.getStyleClass().removeAll("deactive", "Online", "Offline");`, as you don't want to remove the default style classes such as `table-row-cell`, etc.

Comment: this also works, thanks

Comment: _this also works_ is rather upside-down: your solution is wrong (even though it appears to work as expected) for the reason noted by @James_D - please change to James's suggestion to not confuse future readers :)

Comment: so better ? i changed it with a comment